# Server and client side programming language and frameworks to use in embedded systems

Tags: linux, apache, model-view-controller, user-interface, embedded-linux

I am going to implement an easy-to-use and eye-catching graphical user interface for management and configuration of an ethernet switch which has a flash (of just 16 MB) mounted in it, which will have an embedded linux, some specialized softwares, CLI and GUI.

I think, I should go for a web-based graphical user interface so that an admin can access it using the switch's IP. At client side I am thinking of using HTML5 or HTML4 with Javascript as GUI developed in Flex will probably take much more flash space.

However, I don't have a clear idea of server side technology to be used. Should I go for mini-apache for embedded systems with PHP (as I am familiar with Apache+PHP on x86 systems)? or is there a better alternative?

Also, should I go for a MVC type of architecture? Are there some great MVC frameworks developed for embedded systems?

**Update:**
  Basically, I only need to provide a GUI on top of a CLI running on switch. Basic workflow of the application will be something like:

1. User access GUI through a web interface
2. User performs an action on GUI
3. A CLI command corresponding to the action performed is sent to the
   server (running on switch)
4. Server runs the CLI command on the switch
5. Server returns result of the command back to GUI

Comment: I answered here, but perhaps http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I'd skip the web frontend and implement an SNMP server.

Comment: It could depend upon the market. If the device is a consumer (or SOHO) device, providing both SNMP & HTTP interfaces would be probably better. If the device is for professional corporate market only, SNMP only may be sensible

Comment: To elaborate: Any web frontend, however sophisticated, will only be usable for humans, however network configuration is largely "apply this change over all switches in building C".

Comment: No, a web interface could provide web services, and these are usable by automated scripts.

Comment: In principle, yes. In practice, it lacks standardization and has too many layers which each introduce failure modes; alone the fact that SNMP can be encapsulated in Ethernet frames without an IP layer is a killer feature as it allows configuring devices that do not have an IP address.

Comment: Can you help with this question too http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/129813/lua-vs-shell-scripting-vs-c-for-cgi-scripting-on-embedded-devices? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an HTTP server library like [Onion](https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion/wiki) (in C), [GNU libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/) (in C), or [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) (in C++) to make your own specialized HTTP server (embedded inside your device).

You could also use [Ocsigen](http://ocsigen.org/) in Ocaml for the same purpose.

I don't think that embarking a complete HTTP server (apache, or perhaps better [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/)) with a PHP stack makes real sense on an embedded device (the code stack would be much bigger). On such a device the performance does not matter much (you won't get thousands of HTTP requests per second), but the code space (and process space, ie memory consumption) is quite important. (And the specialized web server solution I am suggesting uses only compiled code, which would run faster than interpreted PHP).

If you insist on having a `lighttpd` or `apache` web server in your device -which I believe is wrong-, you could make your application a FastCGI application (and code it in C, C++, Ocaml, ...).

As Simon Richter commented, you could consider making it (also) an [SNMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNMP) service.

Comment: I have checked the embedded linux on the switch with me and I found that 'httpd' was there listed in the running processes list means I have a webserver running on it, right?

Comment: Probably yes (and it could be a lighttpd). But it might not be the best solution. If you want to keep it, consider a FastCGI thing. But I thought your question was about designing the thing from scratch...

Comment: Switch is actually using BusyBox and 'httpd' is part of that BusyBox. I only want to implement some HTML+CSS+Javascript forms which may be used by an admin (by accessing them via a browser) to perform operations on switch e.g. view QoS policies. I, however, understand your point that lighttpd and FastCGI might not be the best solution.

Comment: Can you help with this question too http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/129813/lua-vs-shell-scripting-vs-c-for-cgi-scripting-on-embedded-devices? :)

Comment: Perhaps you should consider disabling the httpd from busybox and providing your own... ?